# How to convert java LocalDateTime to DolphinDB timestamp?

Tags: java, dolphindb

I have a java time

```java
LocalDateTime.of(2018,11,12,8,1,1,123456789);
```

How to convert to timestamp that can be insert to the table in DolphinDB Server?

Comment: have you tried with any code ?

Comment: By far most of the modern JDBC drivers accept that you pass a `LocalDateTime` directly to them without converting to the outmoded and poorly deisgned `Timestamp` class first. Doesn’t yours? `yourPreparedStatement.setObject(5, LocalDateTime.of(2018,11,12,8,1,1,123456789));`.